# Can a html text area have a combination of read only and editable text

Tags: php, html, textarea

this a is quite an open question regarding a `<textarea>` that is embedded within a form.

Is at all possible to have read only text that can not be edited and then within the same `<textarea>` an option to start writing text.

My problem is that I can have only one or the other. If not is there any solutions to have a hard coded message appear in the `<textarea>` before the text can be written.

Thanks for your time and sorry for the newbie sort or question.

Comment: You can add `readonly` attribute, then none can edit the field. But I don't get your question clearly

Comment: why dont u show text in some containers like 'div', and on onclick are some events, using javascript/jquery flip that as editable textarea ,(may be by creating hidden textarea on pageload)?

Answer (score 4):

> Can a html text area have a combination of read only and editable text

No.

> If not is there any solutions to have a hard coded message appear in the before the text can be written.

```
<p>The quick brown <input name="jumping_animal">
   jumped over the lazy <input name="lazy_animal">.</p>
```

Comment: Is the above example instead of implementing a <textarea> as the code would just be displayed as text?

Comment: Yes, that's a complete example, not something to place inside a textarea element.

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be a textarea?

[Try editing the blue text](http://jsfiddle.net/W46Fv/)

```
<div>
    sadsaasdfasd sadfasdf sa sd <span contenteditable>sadf asdf</span>
</div>
```

Comment: SecurityAlert - 'contenteditable' will allow all type of contents scripts,css,styles etc,.

Comment: @gnanz Thats true, but it can only do anything that editing the html from the client side can do

Comment: here editable field is in Form(in question), so the user wants that to stored somewhere and going to display that in some page. that time it will surely affect the application. you can anything like XSS etc,.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can't have both read only text with writable property for a textarea.

Answer to your second question:

```
<script>
    $('#input_textarea').focus(function() {
       if( $(this).val() == "Some text...." ) {
           $(this).val("");
       }           
    });
    $('#input_textarea').blur(function() {
       if( $(this).val() == "" ) {
           $(this).val('Some text....');
       }           
    });
</script>
```

This will work as a placeholder for your textarea.

Comment: Sorry for the naive question, how would this be implemented? Guessing I would use the <textarea> id number but then i'm a lil' stumped after that. Just trying to see what would happen.

Comment: replace #input_textarea with the id of your textarea and "Some text..." with the message you want to show to the user. Remember the text message should exactly be copied to both places where "Some text.." is written.